# React Native redux form go to next field in on SubmitEditing

Tags: react-native, redux-form

I want to focus next field but a cant do that here is my code. I used function for render component.But a cant do that.

```
   export const Input = ({
      imageLeft,
      imageRight,
      containerStyle,
      inputStyle,
      ...props,
      focus,
    }) => (
      <View
        style={StyleSheet.flatten([styles.containerStyle, containerStyle])}
      >
        { imageLeft && <Image
          style={leftImageColor(focus)}
          source={placeholderImageAssets[imageLeft]}
        /> }
        <TextInput
          ref={props.refField}
          autoCorrect={false}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          autoCapitalize='sentences'
          keyboardType='default'
          placeholderTextColor={placeHolderColor(focus)}
          {...props}
          style={StyleSheet.flatten([styles.inputStyle, inputStyle])}
        />
        { imageRight && <Image
          style={styles.imageRight}
          source={checkMarkImageAssets[imageRight]}
        /> }
      </View>
    )
```

And i render this method form component

```
<Field
                ref={(componentRef) => this.field2 = componentRef}
                refField="field2"
                name='lastName'
                placeholder='Last Name'
                component={Input}
                validate={[required()]}
                placeholderTextColor='#fff'
                containerStyle={styles.textInputContainerStyle}
                inputStyle={styles.textInputStyle}
              />
```

and showing error

> stateless function components cannot have refs.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the functions are stateless components and classes are components with state and if you are working with redux-form and you use the ref, you should set prop withRef to true
withRef : boolean [optional]

> If true, the rendered component will be available with the
>   getRenderedComponent() method. Defaults to false. Cannot be used if
>   your component is a stateless function component
>   https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/field.md/

You should to convert Input function to a class, example:

```
export class Input extends React.Component {
render(){
const {
      imageLeft,
      imageRight,
      containerStyle,
      inputStyle,
      ...props,
      focus,
    } = this.props;
return(
      <View
        style={StyleSheet.flatten([styles.containerStyle, containerStyle])}
      >
        { imageLeft && <Image
          style={leftImageColor(focus)}
          source={placeholderImageAssets[imageLeft]}
        /> }
        <TextInput
          ref={props.refField}
          autoCorrect={false}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          autoCapitalize='sentences'
          keyboardType='default'
          placeholderTextColor={placeHolderColor(focus)}
          {...props}
          style={StyleSheet.flatten([styles.inputStyle, inputStyle])}
        />
        { imageRight && <Image
          style={styles.imageRight}
          source={checkMarkImageAssets[imageRight]}
        /> }
      </View>
);
}
}
```

The Field:

```
<Field 
ref={ref => this.field1 = ref}
component={Input}
withRef
/>
```